# Browser Cache Control, Dynamic Content

Tags: browser, mod-perl2, cache-control

**Problem:** I can't seem to get FireFox to cache images sent from a dynamic server

**Setup:** Static Apache Server with reverse proxy to a dynamic server (mod_perl2) at backend.

Here is the request URL for the server.  It is sent to the the dynamic server, where the cookie is used to validate access to the image:

**Request Headers**

```
Host:  <OBSCURED>
User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.15) Gecko/2009102815 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Firefox/3.0.15
Accept:  image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset:  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive:  300
Connection:  keep-alive
Referer: <OBSCURED>
Cookie:  pz_cred=4KCNr0RM15%2FJCOt%2BEa6%2BL62z%2Fxvbp2xNQHY5pJw5d6Q
Pragma:  no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The dynamic server streams the image back to the server, and provides the following response:

**Response Headers**

```
Date:  Tue, 24 Nov 2009 04:28:07 GMT
Server:  Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) mod_apreq2-20051231/2.6.0 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Content-Length:  25496
Content-Type:  image/jpeg
Via: 1.1 127.0.1.1:8081
Keep-Alive:  timeout=15, max=75
Connection:  Keep-Alive
```

So far, so good (me thinks).  However, **on reload of the page**, the image does not appear cached, and a request is again sent:

**Request Headers**

```
Host: <OBSCURED>
User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.15) Gecko/2009102815 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Firefox/3.0.15
Accept:  image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset:  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive:  300
Connection:  keep-alive
Referer: <OBSCURED>
Cookie:  pz_cred=4KCNr0RM15%2FJCOt%2BEa6%2BL62z%2Fxvbp2xNQHY5pJw5d6Q
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

It doesn't seem that request should happen as the browser should have cached the image.  As it is, a 200 response is received, same as the first, and the image appears to be re-fetched (although the browser does appear to be using the cached images).

The problem appears to be hinted at by the Cache-Control: max-age=0 in the reload request header, above.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Perhaps it is the **Via** header in the response that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**My previous answer was only partially correct.**

**The problem** is the way FireFox 3 handles reload events.  Apparently, it almost always requests content again from the origin server.  Thus the `Cache-Control: max-age=0` request header.

Firefox **does** use cached images to render a page on reload, but then it still makes all the requests to update them "in the background".  It then replace them as they come in.

Therefore, the page renders fast, YSlow reports cached content.  But the server is still getting nailed.

**The resolution** is to interrogate the incoming headers in the dynamic server script and determine if a 'If-Modified-Since' header is provided.  If this is the case, and it is determined the content has not changed, an HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED (304) response is returned.

This is not optimal -- I'd rather Firefox not make the requests at all -- but it cuts the page load time in half, and greatly reduces bandwidth.  Given the way Firefox works on reload, this appears the best solution.

**Other Comments**: Jim Ferran's point about navigating away from page and returning has merit -- the cache is always used, and no requests are outgoing (+1 to Jim).  Also, content that is dynamically added (e.g. AJAX calls after the initial load) appear to use the cache as well.

Hope this helps someone besides me :)

Answer (score 5):

The original request has

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

which tells all the intermediate HTTP caches (including Firefox's) that you don't want to use a cached response, you want to get the response from the origin web server itself.

The response says:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
```

which tells everyone that as far as the origin server is concerned, the response *may* be cached.  The server seems to be configured to enable the PNG image to be cached: [HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (section 14.21) says:

> Note: if a response includes a
>   Cache-Control field with the max-age
>   directive (see section 14.9.3), that
>   directive overrides the Expires field.

Your second request says:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

which tells all the intermediate HTTP caches that you won't take any cached response older than 0 seconds.

One thing to watch out for: if you hit the Reload button in Firefox, you are asking to reload from the origin web server.  To test the caching of the image, navigate away from the page and back, or open it up in a new tab.  Not sure why you saw no-cache the first time and max-age=0 the second though.

BTW, I like the FireBug plug-in for Firefox.  You can take a look at the request and response headers with it and all sorts of other good stuff.

Comment: Hi Jim:

Thank you for your help!

The first request originates from Firefox when I press shift-reload.  This seems appropriate, as I am explicitly asking for "fresh" content.

And the first response seems correct too; it has the intended headers.

The second request happens on browser reload /without/ shift.  The expectation is that the firefox cache would then honor the first response, e.g. max-age=31536000. It looks like the server says all images (image/*) are cacheable.

If all that is correct, then the question is what is making FireFox ignore the cache directives?

Comment: I should add, cache is enabled in FireFox, and it is successfully caching images from the static server.  I have also removed the via headers, but no love.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like solved it:

- Removed the proxy via header
- Added a Last-Modified header
- Added a far-future expires date

Firebug still shows 200 responses from the origin server, however, YSlow recognizes the images as cached.  According to YSlow, total image download size when fresh is greater than 500K; with the cache primed, it shows 0K download size.

Here is the response header from the Origin server which does the trick:

```
Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2009 08:54:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) mod_apreq2-20051231/2.6.0 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0
Last-Modified: Sun, 22 Nov 2009 07:28:25 GMT
Expires: Tue, 30 Nov 2010 19:00:25 GMT
Content-Length: 10883
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=89
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Because of the way I'm requesting the images, it really should not matter if these dates are static; my app knows the last mod time before requesting the image and appends this to the request URL on the client side to create a unique URL for each image version, e.g. http://myserver.com/img/125.jpg?20091122 (the info comes from a AJAX JSON feed).    I could, for example, make the last modified date 01 Jan 2000, and the Expires date sometime in the year 2050.

If YSlow is correct -- and performance testing implies it is -- then FireBug should really report these local cache hits instead of a 200 response.

Comment: ps I have filed a bug with FireBug over the reported 200 responses from the local cache